# Join the table with incremental data of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am trying to implement a logic in Redshift Spectrum where my original table looks like below:

Records in the student table:

```
1 || student1 || Boston   || 2019-01-01  
2 || student2 || New York || 2019-02-01
3 || student3 || Chicago  || 2019-03-01 
1 || student1 || Dallas   || 2019-03-01
```

Records in the incremental table studentinc looks like below:

```
1 || student1 || SFO       || 2019-04-01
4 || student4 || Detroit   || 2019-04-01
```

By joining both student and studentinc tables, I am trying to get the latest set of records which should look like below:

```
2 || student2 || New York  || 2019-02-01
3 || student3 || Chicago   || 2019-03-01
1 || student1 || SFO       || 2019-04-01
4 || student4 || Detroit   || 2019-04-01
```

I have got this solution by doing UNION of both student and studentinc, then querying the result of union based on max(modified_ts). However, this solution isn't good for huge tables, is there a better solution which works by joining both the tables?

Comment: 'sn't good for huge tables' - Have you proved this or are you surmising? AND what are you calling huge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend window functions:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by studentid order by date desc) as seqnum
      from ((select s.* from student
            ) union all
            (select i.* from incremental
             from incremental
            )
           ) s
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  The `union all` requires that the columns be exactly the same and in the same order.  You may need to list out the columns if they are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

> **1. Using Spark-SQL** you can achieve this by using not in and union

```
scala> var df1 = Seq((1 ,"student1","Boston  " , "2019-01-01"  ),(2 ,"student2","New York" , "2019-02-01"),(3 ,"student3","Chicago " , "2019-03-01" ),(1 ,"student1","Dallas  " , "2019-03-01")).toDF("id","name","country","_date")
```

register as temp table

```
scala> df1.registerTempTable("temp1")
scala> sql("select * from temp1") .show
+---+--------+--------+----------+
| id|    name| country|     _date|
+---+--------+--------+----------+
|  1|student1|Boston  |2019-01-01|
|  2|student2|New York|2019-02-01|
|  3|student3|Chicago |2019-03-01|
|  1|student1|Dallas  |2019-03-01|
+---+--------+--------+----------+
```

2nd DataFrame

```
scala> var df3 = Seq((1 , "student1", "SFO", "2019-04-01"),(4 , "student4", "Detroit", "2019-04-01")).toDF("id","name","country","_date")

scala> df3.show
+---+--------+-------+----------+
| id|    name|country|     _date|
+---+--------+-------+----------+
|  1|student1|    SFO|2019-04-01|
|  4|student4|Detroit|2019-04-01|
+---+--------+-------+----------+
```

performing not in with union clause

```
scala> sql("select * from (select * from temp1 where id not in (select id from temp2 ) )tt") .union(df3).show
+---+--------+--------+----------+
| id|    name| country|     _date|
+---+--------+--------+----------+
|  2|student2|New York|2019-02-01|
|  3|student3|Chicago |2019-03-01|
|  1|student1|     SFO|2019-04-01|
|  4|student4| Detroit|2019-04-01|
+---+--------+--------+----------+
```

**2nd using Spark Dataframe** this is faster than IN query becoz IN performs a row-wise operation.

```
scala> df1.join(df3,Seq("id"),"left_anti").union (df3).show
+---+--------+--------+----------+
| id|    name| country|     _date|
+---+--------+--------+----------+
|  2|student2|New York|2019-02-01|
|  3|student3|Chicago |2019-03-01|
|  1|student1|     SFO|2019-04-01|
|  4|student4| Detroit|2019-04-01|
+---+--------+--------+----------+
```

Hope it helps you. let me know if you have any query related to the same